# Multiple ConsoleKey variables

Tags: c#, console-application

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;

namespace LearningKeys
 {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {       

       while (true)
            {     

            ConsoleKeyInfo Menu;
            Menu = Console.ReadKey(true);



            Console.WriteLine("1. Pick Item");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Display all Items");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Pick Special Item");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Quit");




            if (Menu.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1. Pick Item");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Display all Items");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Pick Special Item");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Quit");


            }

            ConsoleKeyInfo DisplayAllItems;
            DisplayAllItems = Console.ReadKey(true);

           if (DisplayAllItems.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1. Mushrooms \n2. Sword \n3.Boots"); 



            }


            Console.Read();

            break;

            }
     }
   }
}
```

Hello there, I was wondering why my top 4 Console.WriteLine's disappear when I put the ConsoleKeyInfo variable on top of it. Or why the program does not work when I have more than one Consolekey assigned? I'm sure it is because of the Console.ReadKey(); but I'm not sure of what else to use. I'm just learning ConsoleKeys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console.ReadKey is blocking meaning the program will hang until you press a key. You are not seeing the writelines because the program is waiting for a key

It has nothing to do with how many ConsoleKeyInfo variables you have.

Comment: you know your a noob when it takes you a day to think on the answer xD I just have one variable taking up all of the if statements. However, it does not loop, so I still need to figure out why it doesn't.